# How to make python output show in order?

Tags: python

```
    mesaj = input("Write something !!")
    
    if ("a") in mesaj:
        print ("bi")
    
    if ("b") in mesaj:
        print ("za")
    
    if ("c") in mesaj:
       print ("la")
```

input : `bca`

output : `bi za la`

expected output : `za la bi`

any way to make that work?

Comment: Iterate over each character in the string and change your if statements to check if each character matches. Then it will evaluate b then c then a

Comment: you want the output in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you got the wrong output was because the program tested your conditions in the order you gave them. You need to test every letter from the message, letter by letter. The correct program is this:

```
mesaj = input("Write something !!")

for i in mesaj:

    if i == 'a':
        print("bi")

    if i == 'b':
        print("za")

    if i == 'c':
        print("la")
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/p74lnw.
This does the same thing.
So do the other that ppl have commented.
I didn`t think this was so complicated lmao.
Thx for the help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can also assign output value to `dict` and call it like this:

```py
>>>d = {"a":"bi", "b":"za", "c":"la"}
>>>m = input("Write order: ")
Write order: >? bca
>>>for order in m:
...    if order in d.keys():
...       print(d[order])
za
la
bi
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```py
mesaj = input("Write something !!")

for char in mesaj:
    if char == "a":
        print("bi ", end='')
    elif char == "b":
        print("za ", end='')
    elif char == "c":
        print("la ", end='')
```